# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.(C# web application)

Tags: c#

Please Help Me...from last two days I am facing this issue

My Connection class

```
public class Connection
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;

    public void connclose()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    public Connection()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=ADMIN-PC;database=sample;Integrated security=true");
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
    }

    public void nonquery(string qry)
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

My Class

```
public class Master
{
    Connection conn = new Connection();

    public void insert(string name, string place, string company, string post)
    {
        string qry = "insert into company values('" + name + "','" + place + "','" + company + "'.'" + post + "')";
        conn.nonquery(qry);
    }
}
```

Am not asking you to debug code for me...please just point what is the error..I am a beginner so please..

Comment: possibly your connection could not be established, so the variable 'conn' is null

Comment: First of all in the `Connection` class constructor you don't need to declare `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` again. 2nd you need to be careful about SQL Injection (use parameterized query).

Comment: On another point to add what Hassan said, `SqlConnection` is designed to be created and distroyed frequently. Put the connections in using blocks in the sections of code that actually has the `SqlCommand` when you "close" a connection it actually goes back in to a "Connection Pool" where it can be re-used by future connections to the same connection string.

Comment: Hey and your insert query you used "','" instead of "'.'" after company

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to instantiate fields of your Connection class in a constructor but instead of it creating a local variables. So in terms of scope you are hiding your `conn` and `cmd` variables.

Try this:

```
public Connection()
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=ADMIN-PC;database=sample;Integrated security=true");
    cmd = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
public class Connection
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;

    public void connclose()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    public Connection()
    {
        // initializing global variables
        conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=ADMIN-PC;database=sample;Integrated security=true");
        cmd = null;
    }

    public void nonquery(string qry)
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: some explanation on why this fixes the problem would be very useful.

Comment: you've declared SqlConnection as 'conn' globally but again you're trying to create a new SqlConnection object named 'conn' locally in constructor. when you try conn.Open() in nonquery method, you're accessing global variable and that varibal isn't initialized because in constructor you're initializing local variable

Comment: Thank You llya lvanov,Zohaib Aslam and JleruOHeP for your great support..My Problem got solved..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Although answer has been selected (which exactly solves the issue here) but still I would like to post my answer which uses SqlCommand Parameters.

```
public class Connection
{
   SqlConnection conn;
   SqlCommand cmd;

   public void connclose()
   {
     conn.Close();
   }

   public Connection()
   {   
       conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=ADMIN-PC;database=sample;Integrated security=true");        
       cmd = null;
   }

   public void nonquery(string qry, string[] arrParams, string[] arrParamsVals)
   {          
      try
      {
          conn.Open();
          cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);

          for(int i=0; i < arrParams.Length; i++)
             cmd.Paratmeters.AddWithValue(arrParams[i], arrParamsVals[i]);

          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      }
      catch{}
      finally { conn.Close(); }          
   }
 }
```

**Master Class**:

```
public class Master
{
    Connection conn = new Connection();

    public void insert(string name, string place, string company, string post)
    {
       string qry = "Insert into company values(@name, @place, @company, @post)";
       string[] arrParams= {"@name", "@place", "@company", "@post"};
       string[] arrParamsVals= {name, place, company, post};
       conn.nonquery(qry, arrParams, arrParamsVals);
    }
 }
```